# gzip compression through cloudfront blocks loading through an iframe

Tags: iframe, compression, gzip, amazon-cloudfront, datadog

I recently enabled website compression through CloudFront that compress all compressible files (html, js, css).
It seemed to work fine on each browser I try it from but recorded browser tests failed over and over (both in datadog and in ghost inspector).
This is the error I get "Your website does not support being loaded through an iframe".
Did anyone came across with something similar to this?

I will appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Can't comment on the testing tools, but one possibility to rule out is to see if CloudFront is returning an X-Frame-Options header that blocks iframes. Wondering if you potentially added this with a Response Header Policy in CloudFront when you created/updated your Cache Policy to support compression.

Comment: Hi @Cristian, thank you for responding! I did not added this with response header policy. Can you elaborate more on that matter? thanks again

Comment: The X-Frame-Options header can be used to block your content from being loaded in an iFrame. Response Header Policies is a way to add that header using CloudFront, but it can also be added by your origin/application. I would check to see if that header is being returned as a possible cause of your website not being loadable in an iframe.